# Bash: Variable string contains variable string with special characters (e.g. "=", "'")

Tags: bash

I want to do a basic

```
if [[ "$string" =~ "$substring" ]]; then
  echo "True"
else echo "False"
fi
```

However, the substring I am looking for looks like "THING = '$VAR '" and that just doesn't fly. Yes, $VAR is a variable in my code. Help?

Here's an example of what I am looking at (the $string is extracted from a file):

```
# $string = "THIS = stuff / more random letters taking up space MORE STUFF = '42 ' here's some numbers asdgh asdgjhd a;lkdjg asdlkja dddd 'a::' THING = 'R ' more specs = THIS and THAT END"

for VAR in V R I B WA NA HA1 HA4 HA5; do
  substring="SUBSET = '$VAR '"
  if [[ "$string" =~ "$substring" ]]; then
    echo "True"
  else echo "False"
  fi
done
```

I apologize if this is not more illuminating. Perhaps having the variable in so many quotations is not actually bringing up the variable, but when I print out $substring, it says THING = 'V '.

Comment: Basically what is your question

Comment: What I wrote won't work for substrings that looks like "THING = '$VAR '". The if statement returns false once I add the "=" to my $substring variable.

Comment: can I use array, string functions

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your questions. I have a large string `$string` that I know contains THING = 'R ' or THING = 'V ' (or a few other similar versions). When I do the code I put in my original questions, it does just fine finding THING or R, but THING = or 'R ' don't go through.

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/tNNDNG) works. If you mean something else, edit your question such that it contains code we can copy, paste, and run, that doesn't give you the result you want. Thanks.

Comment: @n.m. Beware, in your example `$VAR` expands to an empty string. I agree though, we need a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: @n.m. She says that her substring is this - `"THING = '$VAR '" `

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Added definition of VAR.

Comment: @CarlaJuneCarroll: It would be better you can provide some examples of  `"$string"` and `"$substring"`.

Comment: @user3004356 Which part of "we can copy, paste, and run" needs further expounding?

Comment: FYI, `$string = "THIS [...]"` isn't correct syntax to assign to `string`. I wonder if perhaps the reason your testing isn't working might be that simple? It'd probably be worth building a tested, standalone reproducer for the problem; see http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: I apologize that my question isn't clear. The $string comes from the header of a file I am reading in. It is ridiculously long and I am reading through millions of files. The header has the information I want and is somewhere in the middle. It will ways be of the form THING = 'V ' or the other letters listed above in the for loop. If it is useful, here is an example of a header ($string) where I am looking for SUBSET = 'R ':

Comment: SIMPLE = T / Fits standard BITPIX = -32 / Bits per pixel NAXIS = 2  /Version of SBFITSEXT standard in effect FLIPSTAT= 'Mirror ' SWOWNER = 'Given Surname' / Licensed owner of software SUBSET = 'R ' RA = '20:04:43.4' DEC = '-18:41:08' EPOCH = '2000 ' IMAGETYP= 'object ' OBSERVER= 'Service Observing' mean=1991.573' ZEROCOR = 'Nov 8 14:56 Zero level correction image is Zero.fits' DARKCOR = 'Nov 8 14:56 Dark count correction image is Dark.fits with scale=0.1'FLATCOR = with scale=32692.75' '[24:2048,1:2048]' BIASSEC = '[1:1,1:2048]' LTV1 = -23. CCDPROC = 'Nov 8 14:56 CCD processing done' END

Comment: Due to the character limitations, I shortened the header significantly until I could post it, but it still contains what I am looking for. Please let me know what else I need to explain so my question is clear.

Comment: Can you show output of `cat -vte <<< "$string"` command

Comment: Not completely. Please see my comment just before for a partial output ...

Comment: Is value of `$string` `SUBSET = 'R '`?

Comment: No, that is $substring.

Comment: So `$string` is that huge block of text?

Comment: Yes. $string is what is listed above in its own comment.

Comment: `string` doesn't have the word `SUBSET` in it, `substring` has it. They don't match. What exactly is surprising?